# PHPExcel - are there more border styles other than BORDER_THICK and BORDER_THIN

Tags: styles, border, phpexcel

I'm new to PHPExcel and I'm trying to convert my MySQL db to a presented my data.

I want to know if there are other border styles that PHPExcel supports besides BORDER_THICK and BORDER_THIN.

I want to use top and double bottom border like in Excel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Border styles are all defined in the `PHPExcel_Style_Border` class, in `/Classes/PHPExcel/Style/Border/php`; and you have the following options:

```
/* Border style */
const BORDER_NONE             = 'none';
const BORDER_DASHDOT          = 'dashDot';
const BORDER_DASHDOTDOT       = 'dashDotDot';
const BORDER_DASHED           = 'dashed';
const BORDER_DOTTED           = 'dotted';
const BORDER_DOUBLE           = 'double';
const BORDER_HAIR             = 'hair';
const BORDER_MEDIUM           = 'medium';
const BORDER_MEDIUMDASHDOT    = 'mediumDashDot';
const BORDER_MEDIUMDASHDOTDOT = 'mediumDashDotDot';
const BORDER_MEDIUMDASHED     = 'mediumDashed';
const BORDER_SLANTDASHDOT     = 'slantDashDot';
const BORDER_THICK            = 'thick';
const BORDER_THIN             = 'thin';
```